# How do I add a tag to a GitHub repository from the terminal window using a mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, github, tags, terminal

Basically I want to add a tag, but I can only use the command line, I've tried git tag -m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy:

```
git tag my-tag
git push --all-tags
```

In case you have not pushed your commits yet, you would also want to bring them upstream as well, because pushing the tags does not also push the commits:

```
git push
```

That's it.